# Azure cloud service publishing - where does it go?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, publishing

I created an asp.net mvc project in VS. I created an azure cloud service. Within the VS solution I added an azure project to enable me to publish to my cloud service. The cloud service has a web role and it’s published to a production environment. When I publish the project, I have my domain .cloudapp.net and I can then view my published project from a browser.

Job done. All good so far.

What I’m unclear on (and this is partly because my azure and asp.net mvc knowledge is limited) is **where the project files actually reside** (and the file/folder structure) and how to access them? I know they are on an IIS server somewhere but that’s about it.
With ‘traditional’ websites you have a webserver, a wwwroot folder and you stick your web pages etc into them and can see/access them through ftp etc.

Apart from wanting to know the answer to the above question I actually want to farm out the web ui (view) part to a web developer whilst I concentrate on the back end stuff. He doesn’t have visual studio so I’m unclear on how to best approach this?

I’ve noticed on the windows azure publish summary within my solution that you can enable remote desktop and enable web deploy which I suspect may be of help to me but as the solution is all working fine at the moment and I’m demoing it to a client tomorrow I’m a bit reluctant to make any last minute changes..as I’m sure we’ve all suffered the consequences of that before.

Comment: my apologies for no formatting of the question... preview seemed to include them :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I’m unclear on is where the project files actually reside
>   (and the file/folder structure) and how to access them?

As you have mentioned, these files reside on the server itself. If you connect to your server via Remote Desktop, you can see the files under `D:\sitesroot` folder (actual name of the folder can be found by launching IIS Manager on that server).

Having said that, it is not recommended to make changes to the files directly on the server. This is because if your server goes bad for any reason, Microsoft will provision a new server for you and it takes the code from the package file when you last deployed your application. This the changes you have made on that server will be lost.

Regarding your other question about having somebody focus on front-end development, I'm pretty sure you don't want him to working on production server directly. I'm assuming you have a centralized code repository somewhere where everybody checks in their code and then you build stuff and then deploy it.

Comment: When you say 'If you connect to your server via Remote Desktop'. How do I do that, is it by enabling remote desktop in my azure publish summary/settings from my vs solution/project?

Comment: That's one way to do it. 2nd way to do it is through Windows Azure Portal (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cloud-services/how-to-configure-a-cloud-service/).

Comment: that's great help thanks. Taking note of messing with production release's - If I have a production version (my current one) and also wanted a dev version for the web guy to play with do you know if it's best to create an extra web role for my cloud service and somehow publish my solution to that as well or create a new cloud service and again be able to publish my solution to that (as well as having the option to publish to my production version) - hope that makes sense

Comment: Not an extra web role but what you would want to do is have a second cloud service in which you developer will deploy the code and play with it. So you would have a development cloud service and a production cloud service. HTH.